# Linux mint is showing main desktop panel on the wrong display

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, gui

I have a projector connected to a laptop. I selected the laptop screen as the "Primary monitor":

[image]

However the start menu is on the projector screen. That's not desired. Is there a separate setting for on which monitor should the main menu be?

Here is some info about my OS version:

```
Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 tk: Gtk 2.24.31 wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina 
base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
```

Answer (score 2):

In the XFCE panel settings, select the correct output:

[image]